# Primary key: отдельное поле ID или ключ по 2м полям?

Tags: mysql, sql

Предположим, есть 3 абстрактные таблицы

```
users:
id | login | password
docs:
id | title | filepath
user_docs:
id | user_id | doc_id
```

Вопрос: насколько необходимо поле id в user_docs если можно сделать ключ по 2м полям, и если он действительно необходим, то почему?

Comment: не нужен, это стандартная промежуточная таблица связи многие-ко-многим

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Скорее всего, не нужен

Первичный ключ, в сущности, является ограничением на не-`NULL` и на уникальность. Сделано это затем, чтобы каждое значение первичного ключа однозначно представляло конкретную строку таблицы (или её отсутствие).

- Сделав первичным ключом пару `(user_id, doc_id)` (без `id` вообще), вы сможете отвечать на вопрос **"этот пользователь и документ связаны?"**
- Имея отдельный первичный ключ `id`, вы сможете создавать связь несколько раз, сможете задавать вопрос "а сколько раз связаны?" и **манипулировать каждой строчкой результата отдельно**, если это имеет смысл в вашей модели данных: один пользователь сможет быть привязан к одному документу больше одного раза. Но в таком варианте проще сделать в связующей таблице дополнительное поле "число связей", чтобы избегать роста таблицы в объёме.

  Это может иметь смысл, если у каждой отдельной связи имеются дополнительные свойства (скажем, момент создания). Но тогда есть смысл рассматривать эту "связь" как полноценную сущность.

Comment: Большое спасибо за пояснение

Comment: А то что null не может быть частью составного ключа - это про mysql или теоретически? Sql server такое ограничение не накладывает, насколько я помню.

Comment: @Qwertiy по стандарту SQL `NULL != NULL` и потому констрейнт на уникальность допускает существование нескольких `NULL`'ов, что ломает однозначную идентификацию строк. Это теоретически бессмысленно. О конкретных реализациях сходу не скажу (про Oracle нагуглил, что запрещает), но это общий принцип в РСУБД, не вижу смысла для нарушений. Это, конечно, только про **первичный** ключ таблицы.